# regex pattern to match a type of strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match the below type of strings using a regex pattern in javascript.

```
E.g. /this/<one or more than one word with hyphen>/<one or more than one word with hyphen>/<one or more than one word with hyphen>/<one or more than one word with hyphen>
```

So this single pattern should match both these strings:

```
1. /this/is/single-word
2. /this/is-more-than/single/word-patterns/to-match
```

Only the slash (/) and the 'this' string in the beginning are consistent and contains only alphabets.

Comment: You changed your question. What do the other sections now contain?

Comment: @sln The sections may have hyphen (no spaces) and there may be 3 or 4 sections beyond '/this/'

Comment: Like this `/^\/this(?:\/[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*){3,4}$/` ? Which won't match your `1.` string above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
\/this\/[a-zA-Z ]+\/[a-zA-Z ]+\/[a-zA-Z ]+
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cZ3eS2)

Comment: Why escape the delimeter without actually showing the delimiter in context? Expression matches `/this/ / / `

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this maybe?

```
(\/this\/(\w+\s?){1,}\/\w+\/(\w+\s?)+)
```

break down:

```
\/     # divder
 this  # keyword
\/     # divider
(      # begin section
 \w+   # single valid word character
 \s?   # possibly followed by a space
)      # end section
{1,}   # match previous section at least 1 times, more if possible.
\/     # divider
\w+    # single valid word character
\/     # divider
(      # begin section
 \w+   # single valid word character
 \s?   # possible space
)      # end section
```

[Working example](http://regex101.com/r/aU9bD6)

Answer (score 0):

This might be obvious, however to match each pattern as a separate result, I believe you want to place parenthesis around the whole expression, like so:

`(\/[a-zA-Z ]+\/[a-zA-Z ]+\/[a-zA-Z ]+\/[a-zA-Z ]+)`

This makes sure that TWO results are returned, not just one big group.

Also, your question did not state that "this" would be static, as the other answers assumed...  it says only the slashes are static.   This should work for any text combo (no word `this` required).

**Edit** - actually looking back at your attempt, I see you used /this/ in your expression, so I assume that's why others did as well.

Demo:  http://rubular.com/r/HGYp2qtmAM

Answer (score 0):

Modified question samples:

```
 /this/is/single-word
 /this/is-more-than/single/word-patterns/to-match
```

Modified again `The sections may have hyphen (no spaces) and there may be 3 or 4 sections beyond '/this/'`

Modified pattern  `/^\/this(?:\/[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*){3,4}$/`

```
 ^ 
 /this
 (?:
      / [a-zA-Z]+ 
      (?: - [a-zA-Z]+ )*
 ){3,4}
 $
```