# Regex pattern to match this string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match the below type of strings using a regex pattern in javascript.

```
E.g. /this/<one or more than one word with hyphen>/<one or more than one word with hyphen>/<one or more than one word with hyphen>/<one or more than one word with hyphen>
```

So this single pattern should match both these strings:

```
1. /this/is/single-word
2. /this/is more-than/single/word-patterns/to-be-matched
```

Only the slash (/)and the 'this' in the beginning are consistent and contains only alphabets.

Comment: 'test' in the beginning? Do you mean 'this'? Also it looks like the second example won't match the pattern because there is a section without a word with hyphen.

Comment: What is different from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616534/regex-pattern-to-match-a-type-of-strings

Comment: @anubhava ... the string actually contains hyphen instead of spaces.  I entered the wrong string in the previous question

Comment: Then use hyphen instead of spaces in the regex?

Comment: @anubhava .. thanks it worked by using hyphen instead of spaces

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
^\/this(?:\/[\w\- ]+)+$
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/bY3qV9)

Answer (score 1):

There are some inconsistencies in your question, and it's not quite clear exactly what you want to match.

That being said, the following regex will provide a loose starting point for the exact strings that you want.

```
/this/(?:[\w|-]+/?){1,10}
```

This assumes the ' ' in your url was not intentional. This example will match a url with '/this/' + 1 to 10 additional '/' chunks.

```
(?:)     -> non-matching group
[\w|-]+  -> one or more word characters or a hyphen
/?       -> zero or one slashes
{1,10}   -> 1 to 10 of the previous element, the non-matching group
```